# "Exception in thread" and more

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Power1Eng {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double x, prod = 1;
    int n;
    String s;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("This program prints x(x is a real number) raised to the power of n(n is an integer).\n");

    outer_loop:
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Input x and n: ");
        x = input.nextDouble();
        n = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            prod *= x;
        }

        System.out.printf("%.1f raised to the power of %d is %.4f. Do you want to continue?(Y/N) ", x, n, prod);
        s = input.nextLine();

        if (s.charAt(0) == 'Y')
            continue;
        else if (s.charAt(0) == 'N')
            break;
        else {
            inner_loop:
            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Wrong input. Do you want to continue?(Y/N) ");
                s = input.nextLine();

                if (s.charAt(0) == 'Y')
                    continue outer_loop;
                else if (s.charAt(0) == 'N')
                    break outer_loop;
                else
                    continue inner_loop;
            }   
        }   
    }       
}

}
```

[image]

There was only trivial logical error when I used just `next()` method, but when I changed
`next()` method to `nextLine()` method, this error shows.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems. The first is that your string could be empty, and then fetching the first character will give an exception.

```
if (s.charAt(0) == 'Y')  // This will throw if is empty.
```

Either test the length of the string to see if there is at least one character, or just use [`String.startsWith`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `charAt`:

```
if (s.startsWith('Y'))
```

The second problem is that you entered a new line after your first input, and nextLine reads up to the next new line character only.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for an initial character count, to make sure there are the correct number of characters that you expect. i.e:

```
while (true)
{
    // ... some code ...

    if (s.length() < 1)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // ... some code ...
}
```

This way, you wouldn't even have to continue running the rest of the code, which if the code base were larger, would help to optimize performance.

Answer (score 0):

The "red text" that you see in the console is an indication of text being sent to standard error. In this case, it is an indication that your program has crashed.

The main problem you are encountering is with this logic:

```
System.out.print("Input x and n: ");
x = input.nextDouble();
n = input.nextInt();

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    prod *= x;
}

System.out.printf("%.1f raised to the power of %d is %.4f. Do you want to continue?(Y/N) ", x, n, prod);
s = input.nextLine();
```

Suppose the user input is:

> 2.1 4(enter)

`input.nextDouble()` will take `2.1`, leaving `4(enter)` on the standard input stream.
`input.nextInt()` will take `4`, leaving `(enter)` on the standard input stream.
`input.nextLine()` will take `""` (empty string), finally clearing the `(enter)` from the initial user input of `x` and `n`.